# What is the difference between method header and method signature?

Tags: c#, methods

I want to know what is exactly a method header and what is a method signature and is this the same among programming languages or just in C#?

So, is it correct to say the following is a method header:

```
public void SumNumbers(int firstNumber, int secondNumber)
```

and the following is the method signature:

```
public void SumNumbers(int, int)
```

?

Comment: Definitions of "signature" vary across languages.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [C# spec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645760(v=vs.71).aspx), a *method header* consists of:

> attributes<sub>opt</sub> method-modifiers<sub>opt</sub> return-type member-name (formal-parameter-list<sub>opt</sub>)

So to extend what you've shown:

```
[OperationContract]
public void SumNumbers(int firstNumber, int secondNumber)
```

Above example contains examples of the possible parts that make up a method header, while the minimum (all non-optional parts) would be something like:

```
void Foo()
```

---

As for the signature, see [3.6 Signatures and overloading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691131(v=vs.71).aspx):

> The signature of a method consists of the **name of the method and the type and kind (value, reference, or output) of each of its formal parameters**, considered in the order left to right. The signature of a method specifically does not include the return type, nor does it include the params modifier that may be specified for the right-most parameter.
>
> The following example shows a set of overloaded method declarations along with their signatures.
>
> ```
> interface ITest
> {
>    void F();                  // F()
>    void F(int x);             // F(int)
>    void F(ref int x);         // F(ref int)
>    void F(int x, int y);      // F(int, int)
>    int F(string s);           // F(string)
>    int F(int x);              // F(int)         error, F(int) already exists
>    void F(string[] a);        // F(string[])
>    void F(params string[] a); // F(string[])      error, F(string[]) already exists
> }
> ```

So the *signature* of your second example would be:

```
SumNumbers(int, int)
```

See also [Method Signature in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8808703/method-signature-in-c-sharp) on SO, especially Eric Lippert's answer.